# How to create Folder like MY Photo app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiimageview, uiview-hierarchy

Dear Friends I want to know is there any Possible to create folder like **MY PHOTO** app in iPhone? If it is Possible How can i implement it?

now i am trying to create. i am using UIScrollView in that My Customized UIView like added one UIImageView for set folder image.then using for loop i am creating statically and arrange one by one in one column UIView Down But they Need it will be in two column.how can i implement?

And Also How can i implement it in dynamically? i.e for each  button action one by one folder creating

Comment: Can you give any screen shot what you want exactly? and In one row how many images you want?

Comment: You should probably show some of the code you have thus far. It might be best to keep your posts to a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and set size according to your need.

```
         float horizontal = 8.0;
         float vertical = 8.0;
         int i;
        for(i=0; i<[arrayOfThumbImages count]; i++)
        {
            if((i%2) == 0 && i!=0)
            {
                horizontal = 8.0;
                vertical = vertical + 70.0 + 8.0;
            }
            buttonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [buttonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(horizontal, vertical, 70.0, 70.0)];
            [buttonImage setTag:i];
            [buttonImage setBackgroundImage:[arrayOfThumbImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [buttonImage addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            buttonImage.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
            buttonImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            [myScrollView addSubview:buttonImage];
            horizontal = horizontal + 70.0 + 8.0;

        }
```

Comment: i can't able to upload image because i am a new user how can i  increase my reputation score

Comment: i used your code its fine good. thanks a lot i tried this past two days